# PyQt5: how to open one window in each connected screen?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to create a screenshot utility for linux using python. Right now I'm stuck at trying to implement a function that lets the user select a region from a live screen and screenshot it. After much pondering, I reached the conclusion to create a full-screen window on each screen to get the mouse's click and drag coordinates.
How can I have my program create a full-screen window (without the toolbar icon) for each screen connected to the system?

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc

class InvisWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, screens):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(qtc.Qt.Tool | qtc.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.show()
        self.showFullScreen()
        self.windowHandle().setScreen(screens[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = InvisWindow(app.screens())
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I found this code searching for a way to do it, but no matter which `screen` I pass to `setScreen()` it always appears on a single screen, i.e. changing the argument doesn't change which screen it appears in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. as the [documentation explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#setScreen):

> If the screen is part of a virtual desktop of multiple screens, the window will not move automatically to newScreen.

2. on Linux, there's some amount of time and system events between the call to `show` and when the window is actually *mapped* on the screen the first time (see [Initial Geometry](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#initial-geometry)), which can be overridden by the window manager if no geometry is explicitly set;

That said, there should be no need to use the QWindow for this, as using [`move`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#pos-prop) is usually be enough, you only must do it *before* any call to `show()` or related functions:

```
class InvisWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, screens):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(qtc.Qt.Tool | qtc.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.move(screens[0].geometry().topLeft())
        self.showFullScreen()
```

<sup>Note that there's no use in calling `show()` before `showFullScreen()`, since it implicitly calls `setVisible(True)`.</sup>

If what you want is to show a *single* window on top of everything, then you could try the following:

```
class InvisWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    mapped = False
    def __init__(self, screens):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(
            qtc.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | 
            qtc.Qt.Tool | 
            qtc.Qt.FramelessWindowHint
        )
        self.show()

    def moveEvent(self, event):
        if not self.mapped:
            geometry = qtc.QRect()
            for screen in qtw.QApplication.screens():
                geometry |= screen.geometry()
            if self.pos() != geometry.topLeft():
                self.setGeometry(geometry)
                self.mapped = True
```

Please consider the last lines, as they are very important, because trying to do geometry changes in a geometry change event (`moveEvent` and `resizeEvent`) can cause recursion.

Comment: This works great, thank you! But for some reason `alt+f4` does not stop the script, it only closes the windows. I have to `ctrl+z` in the terminal to stop the script. Do you know why this could be happening?

Comment: @オパラ Uhm, it seems that removing the `Tool` window flag, the problems doesn't occur, and it's triggered by the "inherited" `Popup` flag. Why do you need it? In any case, if you want to ensure that the app is closed when the window is, just override `closeEvent` and add `QApplication.quit()`.